# Would an unexpected T_STRING on line 1 be causing a server error?

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

This is the start of my php document, and it throws up T_STRING errors with validation programs. I have tried viewing the document using XAMPP, and it worked fine, but when I uploaded the document to a server (this is for a class), I was given a server error. To make matters worse, this exact code is in all my other (working) php documents.
The code in its entirety is probably too long to post for a full diagnosis, so I wanted to know if this alone would cause the server error. If not this, what are some common causes?

Other things that seem suspicious:

```
$values = ["","","","","","",""];
```

I don't know if this is how a array should be created/cleared, but it was another error brought up with validation programs.

```
if (strlen($customerlname)>30) {
....
if (!is_numeric($postcode)) {
```

etc. These are supposed to be fine, though they don't seem to be recognised by N++.

The problem is that the document works with XAMPP, just not on the server. Is XAMPP just being nice and "knowing what I mean"? The only part that I can't test in XAMPP is the database connection:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX");
mysql_select_db("XXXX", $conn)
or die ('Database not found '.mysql_error());
```

which again, is in various other (working) documents. Is this probably going to be a server-side issue?

**edit:** I've found the apparent issue, thank you. The document is running now. The problem was the array, had to change a few instances to $variable = array(...); Thank you all for your help. It's also nice to know about phpinfo() for future reference.

Comment: Does the server have `short_open_tag` enabled? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Note that `$values = [...];` is only valid in PHP 5.4+, which is not that common on a lot of hosting environments yet.  Make sure you have 5.4, or change it to `$values = array(...);`

Comment: I don't have access to any of the server's files, I've just been allocated my own folder to upload and test files from, so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` to get your version and to see if short_open_tag is enabled.

Comment: I've updated the line to  $values = array ("","","","","","",""); and it doesn't seem to be working. I'll check I haven't got any more bad arrays.

Comment: I just checked, short_open_tag is off.

Comment: Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

The server is probably seeing the

```
<?
```

as opening PHP tag. (it can be configured as such)

Easiest is to change to something like

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your document is starting at the top with:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

and if you have `short_open_tag=On` enabled in your webserver, PHP is assuming that  by `<?` means, you are starting a PHP document, so, the `xml` after that is evaluating for a string.

To check, if this is the case, then you should turn it off like: `short_open_tag=Off` and try loading your document again

Comment: Checked, and short_open_tag is off.

Comment: @user2375146 then replace this `$values = ["","","","","","",""];` with `$values = array("","","","","","","");` and try again

Comment: Already did that, but it's still failing. Checking that I haven't butchered any other arrays.

Comment: @user2375146 what exactly is on line 1?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is a copy-paste of line 1. The document is working now, three arrays were at fault. Still don't know why validators were complaining about line 1 (probably their short_open_tag setting), but everything's working now, thanks!